# Adding a caption to a graphic inside a longtable with multicolumn?

Tags: captions, longtable, multicolumn

I want to add a \caption or \captionof on the \includegrafics to a figure I added to my longtable. The problem is that I am using multicolumn. All examples I have seen so far just uses 1 column, none of them spans the image to more columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\normalcaption\caption

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{cp{5cm}}
  \caption{this is a long table}\\

zz& zzz\\

a figure $\rightarrow$&
\centering\arraybackslash
\let\caption\normalcaption
 %I want to add a caption to my FIGURE.JPG which is within a multicolumn command.
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{FIGURE.JPG}
\captionof{figure}{a figure}}\\ 
zz zzz& zz zz zz zz zz\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This command does not work. Is there any alternatives or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: please fix your example to be a complete document so people can run it but what do you need other then `\caption{caption goes here}` at the point you have the comment? but your table makerkup is very strange, why all the `\makebox` and `\parbox` nested? the 17cm wide entries are presumably wider than the total specified width of your six 2.5cm p columns

Comment: I want to caption the figure, not the longtable. I tried to insert "begin{figure}" but it seemed not to work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the only portion of the 1000 pages code that really matter, imho, is the longtable. I just need to caption a figure which is within a longtable.

Comment: No the 1000 pages are of no interest but you should always make the example a complete document so people can run it and test answers, add `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}` and any needed packages. But `longtable` has a `\caption` command so as I say you just want to put `\caption{hello}\\` at the point you want a caption.

Comment: if you want to ask about a failure with `\begin{figure}` _put that in the example._ people can not fix code that you have not shown. but  `figure` is a box, you can not put `longtable` in a box otherwise  there can be no page breaking.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the last part of the answer. That kind of answers why I could not add a figure within a longtable. Regarding \caption, I need to caption the figure, which I added with '\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{acs1.jpg}'. I need this graphics to have a caption on its own, regardless of the caption of the longtable. I just tried "\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{acs1.jpg}
    } \caption{TESTE} \\" and it failed.

Sorry, I don't know how to change text into code

Comment: @brunofagioli if you tried that and it failed, you should have put that into your question with enough `\documentclass...` preamble so people can see the error, however see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved using \parbox as stated in another post.

Comment: I updated the initial question. I added a comment on the line trying to explain what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Please always post complete documents as below that allow code to be debugged/tested, but I think you want something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\normalcaption\caption

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{cp{5cm}}
  \caption{this is a long table}\\

zz& zzz\\

a figure $\rightarrow$&
\centering\arraybackslash
\let\caption\normalcaption
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{a figure}
\\
zz zzz& zz zz zz zz zz
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David, thats what I want, indeed. Unfortunately, perhaps because of the multicolumn or anything l don't know yet, it failed to compile.

Comment: `\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{acs1.jpg} \captionof{figure}{a figure}} \\ `

Comment: Could you give me a sample using multicolumn, please?

Comment: use p{6m} not l as captions are vertical displayed material so you can not put in an `l` entry.

Comment: I added a second line on the table with multicolumn and added p{6em} but it fails to compile.

! Misplaced \noalign.\caption ->\noalign\bgroup \@ifnextchar [{\egroup \LT@c@ption \@firstofone ... \captionof{figure}{a figure}}

! Misplaced \noalign.\caption ->\noalign\bgroup \@ifnextchar [{\egroup \LT@c@ption \@firstofone ... \captionof{figure}{a figure}}

Comment: I just changed the original question and added a complete code, as you suggested in the first place.